# What RegEx should I use to split a string according to 2 word format and spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split the string:

```
Chan 0: 2.50 0.12 13.92 83.46,Chan 1: 2.58 85.92 2.47 9.03,Chan 2: 5.00 85.0 33.33 6.64,Chan 3: 0.00 0.00 14.41 85.59
```

I am trying to get just the numbers. I have tried to use the following regex:

```
/(\bChan\s[0-9]\b|\b,Chan\s[0-9]\b):\s|\s/
```

according to regextester.com I should expect 16 string but I am getting 41 when I try to print the length of the var that holds the split string.

My code is:

```
var x = values.value;
var v = x.split(/(\bChan\s[0-9]\b|\b,Chan\s[0-9]\b):\s|\s+/);
console.log(v.length);
```

Additional question: I tried omitting the `|\s` at the end to split the string at the `chan #` string. It does split it I get a length of 9 when I try to print them I am stil able to print the delimiter I used, `Chan #:` I thought that the returned value of split is just the values in between the delimiter I used and not the delimiter itself?

Comment: Please add the code you are using. I guess `.split()`, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh yes. Question Editted

Comment: what does mean *16 string*?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you twice.

Comment: You may use replace the capturing group with a non-capturing one and then after getting all matches, remove empty items. [`s.split(/(?:\bChan\s*[0-9]\b|\b,Chan\s*[0-9]\b):\s*|\s+/).filter(Boolean))`](https://jsfiddle.net/52knrpzf/). Or shrink the pattern to [`/\b,?Chan\s*[0-9]\b:\s*|\s+/`](https://jsfiddle.net/52knrpzf/2/)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I editted the question with my code. by 16 string I mean the array size of the variable holding the splitted string was 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just extract the numbers with a dot in it.

```js
var string = "Chan 0: 2.50 0.12 13.92 83.46,Chan 1: 2.58 85.92 2.47 9.03,Chan 2: 5.00 85.0 33.33 6.64,Chan 3: 0.00 0.00 14.41 85.59",
    values = string.match(/\d+\.\d+/g); 

console.log(values.length);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`(\bChan\s[0-9]\b|\b,Chan\s[0-9]\b):\s|\s`](https://regex101.com/r/BX6wiL/1) regex contains a capturing group, and `String.split()` always puts the captured substring into the resulting array. Besides, the pattern matches at the start of the string, and thus an empty item is placed at the start of the resulting array.

There are several ways to fix the issue and that depends on what the input can be. If you know there is always `Chan`+spaces+digits+`:` between float numbers that are always in the same format, you may use Nina's suggestion, `string.match(/\d+\.\d+/g)` since it simplest.

You may also fix your approach by getting rid of the capturing group and removing empty items:

```js
var x = "Chan 0: 2.50 0.12 13.92 83.46,Chan 1: 2.58 85.92 2.47 9.03,Chan 2: 5.00 85.0 33.33 6.64,Chan 3: 0.00 0.00 14.41 85.59";
var v = x.split(/(?:\b,?Chan\s+\d+:)?\s+/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(v.length);
console.log(v);
```

If you need a way to only grab non-whitespace chunks after `Chan` + digits + `:`, you might consider a 2-step solution: match the substrings after the delimiter and then split:

```js
var x = "Chan 0: 2.50 0.12 13.92 83.46,Chan 1: 2.58 85.92 2.47 9.03,Chan 2: 5.00 85.0 33.33 6.64,Chan 3: 0.00 0.00 14.41 85.59";
var v=[],m;
var rx = /\bChan\s+\d+:\s+([\s\d.]+)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(x)) {
  m[1].split(/\s+/).map(function(c) {return v.push(c);});
}
console.log(v.length);
console.log(v);
```